# Pandas makes hours disappear when recasting column as pd.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given the following data frame:

```
    Name        Loc              DateTime               RecordId    RST
0   SwingBridge (47.57, -122.35) 08/01/2016 12:00:00 AM 1854751     76.06   
1   Roosevelt   (47.69, -122.31) 08/01/2016 12:00:00 AM 1941744     2.26
```

which is read in from  a csv file using

```
filename='my.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(filename, 
                 dtype={'Name': str, 'Loc': object, 
                        'RecordId':int, 'RST': float})
```

If I read the dates using `parse_date=['DateTime']` or recast them as
`df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])`, **why do the bloody hours disappear??**

```
    Name        Loc              DateTime       RecordId    RST
0   SwingBridge (47.57, -122.35) 08/01/2016     1854751     76.06   
1   Roosevelt   (47.69, -122.31) 08/01/2016     1941744     2.26
```

Comment: This is a display issue, if the time is `12:00 AM` then they are not displayed, you can confirm that the data is still there by doing `df['DateTime'].iloc[0]` is there are an issue with this?

Comment: `12:00 AM`, or `00:00` hours represents start of day, and if the time is missing, that is the time implied. It didn't go anywhere, it just isn't displayed because that's how the `__repr__` function was written.

Comment: @EdChum you are right, the hours are still there: `Timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00')`. I infer that I can easily do time averages as if nothing had happened. Would you or @COLDSPEED mind making this an answer for the benefit of those who will need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a display issue, by default when the time is equal to `00:00` or in your case `12:00 AM` then it is not displayed, if you look at the individual element's value, the time component is still there.

Example:

```
In[4]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""DateTime
08/01/2016 12:00:00 AM"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df
Out[4]: 
    DateTime
0 2016-08-01

In[5]:    
df['DateTime'].iloc[0]

Out[5]: Timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00')
```